# Linking glfw and D

Tags: linker, static-libraries, d, glfw

I'm trying to use [glfw 2.7.8](http://www.glfw.org/download.html) with the Digital Mars D compiler version 2.0.

I followed the instructions from the example makefile on copying the .lib files to dm/lib folder, but I have not had success.

An example compile looks like this.

```
dmd main.d
```

The source of the file is:

```
import std.string;
import glfw;
int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is

```
main.d(2): Error: module glfw is in file 'glfw.d' which cannot be read
import path[0] = /usr/share/dmd/src/phobos
import path[1] = /usr/share/dmd/src/druntime/import
```

I have tried on both Windows 7 and Mac OSX 10.8.2, but I have not had success.  Should I compile glfw.d as a lib and then drop it into my main directory?

I have also had _symbol not found messsages when I try to drop the .lib into the main directory and use the -L compiler flags linking to glfw.lib.

Any examples or help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you need some d or di files in the import directory (specified with the -I switch IIRC)

Answer (score 2):

you need to add `-Ipath/to/glfw-x.x.x/support/d/imports` to the compiler directive

you can also add the lib folder (with the def files) with the -L switch so the linker can map the symbols properly to the ones exposed in the dll

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass glfw.d to the compiler:

```
dmd main.d glfw.d
```

assuming it is in the same directory as main.d.